# i want to reset auto increment value on daily basis in mysql

Tags: mysql

my auto increment value as

```
20180809_0001
20180809_0002
20180809_0003
```

and when date changes should start with 1 again

```
20180810_0001
```

I have declared first column as date type and second column id as auto_increment of int and both columns as primary key

Comment: [How to add auto increment id according to a group in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38737506)

Comment: Just store the date and the AI. And don't worry about resetting